# Why do I get this error with 'satisfies' operator?

Tags: typescript

I was reading TS [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) regarding `satisfies` operator.

> The new satisfies operator lets us validate that the type of an
> expression matches some type, without changing the resulting type of
> that expression. As an example, we could use satisfies to validate
> that all the properties of palette are compatible with string |
> number[]:

```
type Colors = "red" | "green" | "blue";
type RGB = [red: number, green: number, blue: number];
const palette = {
    red: [255, 0, 0],
    green: "#00ff00",
    blue: [0, 0, 255] // I fixed this one 
//  ~~~~ The typo is now caught!
} satisfies Record<Colors, string | RGB>;

// Both of these methods are still accessible!
const redComponent = palette.red.at(0);
const greenNormalized = palette.green.toUpperCase();
```

After running this code from documentation in the TS playground, I get this error:

```
Property 'at' does not exist on type '[number, number, number]'.
```

According to the documentation, it should work just fine? Is there an error in documentation?  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: What’s your target version? `at` only exists in the libraries for newer ES releases.  This question has very little to do with `satisfies` and a lot to do with the runtime version of JS you’re telling TS about.

Comment: @jcalz I checked TS playground setting and it's set to ES2017

Comment: You need at least ES2022, see the linked q/a